# Can you use Interop Assemblies with Office 365 client apps?

Tags: powershell, office-interop, office365

With Office 2010/2013 you could download the PIA Primary Interop Assemblies and do stuff that would control Excel etc, like building an ad-hoc spreadsheet.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" 
$app = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
```

Does the same thing work with the Excel in Office 365?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bought Office 365 (Home) and installed it (the click-to-run installer). It must have the interop assemblies built in because the code runs fine and you can automate Excel via PowerShell just like usual.

I looked everywhere on the internet and didn't find a single person ever saying this. So, I'll be the first. Case closed.